# Using Machine Learning to Predict Temperature

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am a beginner in ML and I want to create a smart thermostat, that after collecting enough data from the interaction with the user, it will start to set the home temperature by itself.

What I got so far is the hardware prototype that lets the user set the temperature, and in the same time it posts the Environment and the UserSetTemperature to ThingSpeak (to easily store the data for later access)

The other part is a python algorithm that gets the data from ThingSpeak and it converts it into a Pandas DataFrame.

The data frame looks like bellow:

```
 timeStamp                      environment_temp    user_set_temp  

2018-05-27T00:12:43Z               20            21              
2018-05-27T00:17:27Z               20            22                 
2018-05-27T00:17:59Z               20            24                
2018-05-27T00:20:01Z               20            21                  
2018-05-27T00:23:14Z               20            24                 
2018-05-28T09:39:07Z               20            22             
2018-05-28T10:40:17Z               20            23               
2018-05-28T20:12:47Z               20            25              
2018-05-28T20:14:16Z               23            25               
2018-05-30T20:29:30Z               18            24
```

And here is where I got stuck. I don't know how to use this data with the ML libraries in order to make predictions on how the temperature should be set when the environment temperature is x.

I tried to use the sklearn train_test_split()  and LinearRegression(), but with no significant result

Every suggestion will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: This is more of a machine learning issue than a programming one. Did you plot your data? Did you find correlations? If not, can you add more features to your data set?

Comment: You're right, there is no programming issue. I plotted the data and I couldn't find any correlations, maybe there are some but as I am a total beginner I didn't notice any. The problem that I am facing is that I don't know how to basically use this kind of dataFrame to make predictions.

Comment: Which part of the sklearn docs did you read and find unclear?

Comment: Looking at the first rows, the users upped the temperature almost 20% within 5 minutes. You need to study your problem. Do many users have access to the thermostat? If so, remember that everybody's comfortable temperature is different. That would completely mess with what the thermostat "should" be set at. I suggest looking at Andrew Ng's or Google (Tensorflow)'s Machine Learning courses for more info on the topic.

Comment: @PaulH the documentation is clear, but the way I should apply it is the problem. I can't figure out the way I should use this data.

Comment: @pyb The values that are there are just test data because I wanted to have first a working hardware prototype that collects and posts data to a server. And there will be a single user taken into account

Comment: If you don't know what to do with the data, you have to learn machine learning. this is a programming forum. Try stackexchange data science